# Ubuntu 16.04 create ext4: 500 TB file system

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ext4

The ext4 standard suggest one can create a file system upto 1 EB in size.

My goal is to create 500 TB of ext4 file system on Ubuntu 16.0.4. Check my fs creation command:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -J device=/dev/md125p1 /dev/md125p2 -b 4096 -E stride=128,stripe-width=6400,lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0
```

With this command I get following error:

> Cannot create filesystem with requested number of inodes while setting up superblock

I tried to set bytes per inode value to a very high number using -i option in mkfs.ext4 but still no luck.

I'm aware RHEL recommends max 50 TB of ext4 file system.
Still is it possible to create 500 TB of file system with ext4?

Comment: I would consider ZFS for the filesystem, as it doesn't appear to have the same limits as ext4 per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336961/what-is-the-sense-behind-zfss-limits).  ZFS also comes with a wealth of benefits over ext4, such as being self-healing.  There are cons to setting up ZFS with hardware raid, with software raid being preferable, but hardware raid is supported.

Comment: I'd *strongly* urge you to use a different filesystem for such a large pool of data... You've not divulged the structure of your storage at all, but ZFS is a very good shout, and while you're at it, use a more recent LTS release. Additionally, disabling lazy init with a filesystem of this size will keep the system busy for a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.   Using a modern version of `mke2fs`:

```
% mkfs.ext4 /tmp/test.img 500T
mke2fs 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
Creating regular file /tmp/test.img
Creating filesystem with 134217728000 4k blocks and 4259840000 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 00257d43-0298-4aaf-8cca-37e34f3d1bb8
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544, 1934917632, 
    2560000000, 3855122432, 5804752896, 12800000000, 17414258688, 
    26985857024, 52242776064, 64000000000

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

The number of inodes is capped at `(2**32)-1` automatically, so the concern expressed in the other answer isn't an issue.

Also, using a block size > 4k isn't supported on the x86, because of Linux limitation which requires that the block size can not be larger than the VM page size.  Hence, you can use a block size of up to 64k on the PowerPC, since it has a page size of 64k.

I'll also say that if you are using really big file systems, I strongly encourage you to use the latest version of `e2fsprogs`, and not the obsolete version shipping in Ubuntu 16.04.  There have been a lot of bug fixes in the past 3 years, including some that relate to very large file systems.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski Thanks for the comment. Let me give it a try with Ubuntu 18.04 and latest mke2fs

Comment: @AshishKhurange I just edited the answer. Theodore is the author; and the primary developer and maintainer of `e2fsprogs`, and a maintainer for the ext4 file system. :)

Comment: @Theodore Ts'o Thank you. Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: @Theodore Ts'o thank you very much for your help. I upgraded the OS version of my appliance to Ubuntu 18.04 and without any issue I could create 500 TB ext4 file system. The file system has 4277350848 inodes.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, ext4 may not support 500 TB for blocks of 4K.

A default partition of EXT3/EXT4 has a bytes-per-inode ratio of one inode every
16384 bytes (16 Kb).
Thus we have:

```
500 GB = 500 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 549 755 813 888 000 bytes
549 755 813 888 000 bytes / 16384 = 33 554 432 000 inodes
```

The number of inodes is a 32-bit number, so the maximum possible number of inodes
on any ext2/3/4 file system is 2^32-1 or 4,294,967,295 inodes.

As 33 554 432 000 is much larger than 4,294,967,295, allocating that number of
inodes is impossible. You will need 8 times more than the maximum number of inodes.

Your options as I see are:

- Try to force an inode limit : `-N 4294967295`
- Use blocks of 8x4 = 32 KB, which is wasteful if your files are small
- Use another file-system than ext4.
  I have seen reports that say that XFS can support such a 
  file-system, but cannot say from personal experience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to create the file system with 8KB block size, I could create the file system, but when I tried to mount, it gave me error unrecognized file system. xfs, yes I can create the file system, but I don't want to go there as xfs has no feature to encrypt a directory and export it as NFS share.

Comment: Curiosity: Does ext4 work with blocks of 32 KB? Does `-N` help? Note: For encryption you might use VeraCrypt.